# How can a Mule 4 application get access to common dependencies defined in the domain

Tags: mule, mule4, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

In Anypoint Studio, I have a domain project where I define dependencies (mule connectors and other various 3rd party dependencies) that are common to the apps that are part of the domain. In those apps, I can access the mule connectors, but my java classes that reference packages in the 3rd party dependencies are not resolving. How do I configure the domain to share these dependencies with the apps?